# Blank Image is generated using highchart export server

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have used below commands to install, run and generate chart images from Highcharts export server.

1. ```
   run npm install highcharts-export-server -g
   ```
2. ```
   run highcharts-export-server --enableServer 1
   ```
3. ```
   run curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"infile\": 
   {\"title\": {\"text\": \"Steep Chart\"}, \"xAxis\": {\"categories\": 
   [\"Jan\", \"Feb\", \"Mar\"]}, \"series\": [{\"data\": [29.9, 71.5, 
   106.4]}]}}" 127.0.0.1:7801 -o mychart666.png
   ```

Above steps run HighCharts-export-server v2.0.24 and generates 2KB blank image.

Not sure what is going wrong here.

Comment: From what I have checked on my side, the chart exports correctly. I have used above commands on Windows 8.1 machine. Did you configure the server just as described here: https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server? Please, provide us the installation logs.

Comment: @pawel_d i have figured the problem. While running npm command to install highcharts, there are certain configurations asked during installation. Th problem was, when it was asking for " Which CDN would you like to use?: (https://code.highcharts.com/) y ", i was entering y instead of the url https://code.highcharts.com/). After entering the url, it was working fine.